# help with ant file - classpath for Java task

Tags: java, ant, classpath

I have the below build file for Ant and trying to use the target 'run' for executing the program.

```
<property name="springjar"  location="E:/Tools/spring-30/dist/" />
<property name="logjar"     location="E:/Tools/commons-logging-1.1.1/" />

<patternset id="jar.files"><include name="**/*.jar"/></patternset>

<path id="springlearn.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${springjar}"><patternset refid="jar.files"/></fileset>
    <fileset dir="${logjar}"><patternset refid="jar.files"/></fileset>
</path>


<target name="run" depends="dist" description="Execute the Java Program">
    <java dir ="." fork="true" jar="dist\app.jar" classpathref ="springlearn.classpath">
    </java>
</target>
```

Using the same classpathref, I am able to successfully compile & create the jar, but when use the target run, I get the below error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:289)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
```

Exception in thread "main"

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

From the [`java` task docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html):

> When using the jar attribute, all classpath settings are ignored according to [Sun's specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#-jar).

So the classpath you set up isn't being looked at at all.

You could add `dist/app.jar` to your classpath and call the main class direct:

```
<java dir ="." fork="true" classname="com.yourdomain.YourMainClass">
  <classpath>
    <path refid="springlearn.classpath" />
    <pathelement location="dist\app.jar" />
  </classpath>
</java>
```

If you want to call the jar, you'll need to set up a classpath entry in the manifest when you build it. Have a look at the [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task, it could be useful.

Comment: Thank you! I'm starting tomcat via ant and tomcat's bootstrap.jar doesn't have tomcat-juli.jar in it's Manifest-classpath. So I tried using a different classpath. This doesn't work if you use the "jar" attritbute. I now define the classname to run and provide a classpath myself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a generic Ant build.xml that works well for me.  See if it can help you as well:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="ui" basedir="." default="package">

    <property name="version" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="haltonfailure" value="no"/>

    <property name="out" value="out"/>

    <property name="production.src" value="src"/>
    <property name="production.lib" value="lib"/>
    <property name="production.resources" value="config"/>
    <property name="production.classes" value="${out}/production/${ant.project.name}"/>

    <property name="test.src" value="test"/>
    <property name="test.lib" value="lib"/>
    <property name="test.resources" value="config"/>
    <property name="test.classes" value="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}"/>

    <property name="exploded" value="out/exploded/${ant.project.name}"/>
    <property name="exploded.classes" value="${exploded}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="exploded.lib" value="${exploded}/WEB-INF/lib"/>

    <property name="reports.out" value="${out}/reports"/>
    <property name="junit.out" value="${reports.out}/junit"/>
    <property name="testng.out" value="${reports.out}/testng"/>

    <path id="production.class.path">
        <pathelement location="${production.classes}"/>
        <pathelement location="${production.resources}"/>
        <fileset dir="${production.lib}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            <exclude name="**/junit*.jar"/>
            <exclude name="**/*test*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="test.class.path">
        <path refid="production.class.path"/>
        <pathelement location="${test.classes}"/>
        <pathelement location="${test.resources}"/>
        <fileset dir="${test.lib}">
            <include name="**/junit*.jar"/>
            <include name="**/*test*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="testng.class.path">
        <fileset dir="${test.lib}">
            <include name="**/testng*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <available file="${out}" property="outputExists"/>

    <target name="clean" description="remove all generated artifacts" if="outputExists">
        <delete dir="${out}" includeEmptyDirs="true"/>
        <delete dir="${reports.out}" includeEmptyDirs="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="create" description="create the output directories" unless="outputExists">
        <mkdir dir="${production.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${test.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${junit.out}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${testng.out}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${exploded.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${exploded.lib}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${reports.out}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="compile all .java source files" depends="create">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="production.class.path" refid="production.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${production.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="${out}/production/${ant.project.name}" debug="on" source="${version}">
            <classpath refid="production.class.path"/>
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*Test.java"/>
        </javac>
        <javac srcdir="${test.src}" destdir="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}" debug="on" source="${version}">
            <classpath refid="test.class.path"/>
            <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="junit-test" description="run all junit tests" depends="compile">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="test.class.path" refid="test.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${test.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="${haltonfailure}">
            <classpath refid="test.class.path"/>
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${junit.out}">
                <fileset dir="${test.src}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
        <junitreport todir="${junit.out}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.out}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report todir="${junit.out}" format="frames"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>

    <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpathref="testng.class.path"/>
    <target name="testng-test" description="run all testng tests" depends="compile">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="test.class.path" refid="test.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${test.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <testng classpathref="test.class.path" outputDir="${testng.out}" haltOnFailure="${haltonfailure}" verbose="2">
            <classfileset dir="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}" includes="**/*.class"/>
        </testng>
    </target>

    <target name="exploded" description="create exploded deployment" depends="testng-test">
        <copy todir="${exploded.classes}">
            <fileset dir="${production.classes}"/>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${exploded.lib}">
            <fileset dir="${production.lib}"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="package" description="create package file" depends="exploded">
        <jar destfile="${out}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${production.classes}" includes="**/*.class"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: I don't see a java target here. So I don;t think this answers the questions.

Comment: It does show how to properly set classpath in Ant.  It was intended as an example that the OP could have used when they first asked this question almost six years ago.  Find a better use for your time than comments like this.