# Unable to start main() from jar using ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build, jar

I have a project, say **A** and a jar included in its build path, say **a**. The jar contains a main method and its classname is provided in the Manifest file.

From **A**'s build.xml I am calling the jar file using code as below :

```
<java jar="lib/a.jar" fork="true">
      <arg value="test param" />
</java>
```

Manifest file points to : **myframework.Startup**

When I try to run the ant file I get :

```
 [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
 [java]     at myframework.Startup.<clinit>(Startup.java:40)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
 [java]     ... 1 more
 [java] Could not find the main class: myframework.Startup. Program will exit.
 [java] Exception in thread "main" 
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

---

But when I run the jar file Directly from my editor, Eclipse, i.e. *Right Click a.jar-> Run As -> Java Application* it runs fine.

Please help.

Comment: You don't have log4j on your classpath.

Comment: I have log4j and every other jar needed to run my project in the build file on the top.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988566/help-with-ant-file-classpath-for-java-task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to access a **Parent Project(A)** contents from the **Child Jar(a)**. As per oracle's specifications [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) and Ant documentations [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html), the *classpath* entries are ignored while using jar attribute in java task.

```
<java jar="jarFile.jar">
     <classpath>
          ... ... ...
     </classpath>
</java>
```

The classpath is ignored.

As I was trying to call a main() present in the jarFile (**a**), I specified the classname in the manifest file. The main() needed to use the classes from the Project (**A**) but unfortunately these classes are not available as per the oracle's standards.

Then I tried to use a new strategy :

```
<unzip the jar file to project bin directory />
<java classpath="jar file's main Class Name">
    ... ... ...
</java>
```

By unzipping the jar file contents to the project bin/ directory the jar file (**a**)'s classes were available in the main project (**A**) and then my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices. Change your java task to include log4j on the classpath:

```
<java classname="${jar.main.class}" fork="true">
  <classpath>
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/> 
  </classpath>
  <arg value="test param" />
</java>
```

Or update the manifest of your jar to include the "Class-Path" directive:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.file}" basedir="${classes.dir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${jar.main.class}" />
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/a.jar lib/log4j.jar .. .." />
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

Executable jars must contain both main class and classpath.

See the following answer for more information:

- [Execute Java programs in a consistent environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442706/execute-java-programs-in-a-consistent-environment/19468304#19468304)