# How to run a jar file using ant and set the dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, build, ant, ivy

### Problem Description

1. I am trying to build a jar file of a Java Swing project using ant command
2. The jar file is successfully created but when running, it can't resolve the dependencies somehow and giving the below error.

### Attempts

1. Reinstalling ivy, ant and downloading the dependencies.
2. I have tried changing the classpath multiple times while compiling the project.
3. Also copied the lib folder in the jar file.
4. Tried taking help from ChatGPT, but neither of the solutions worked.

Here's the file structure:

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pogUJ.png)

### Code Structure

1. Here is the important portion of build.xml

```xml
    ...
    <property name="main.class" value="swing.bank.SignUp"/>
    <target name="init" depends="clean" description="--> create directories">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="resolve-dependencies" depends="init" description="--> retrieve dependencies with Ivy">
        <ivy:retrieve />
    </target>
    <target name="copy-resources" depends="resolve-dependencies" description="--> Copy resources to build directory">
        <copy todir="${build.dir}">
            <path refid="assets"/>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${build.dir}/lib">
            <path refid="classpath"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="copy-resources" description="--> Compile source files">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="--> Create distribution">
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/SwingBank.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
```

2. Here is the run configuration in run.xml:

```xml
    <target name="run" description="--> runs the project">
        <java jar="${dist.dir}/SwingBank.jar" fork="true" failonerror="true" maxmemory="128m"/>
    </target>
```

### Error:

This is the error:

```bash
$> ant -f run.xml
ANT_OPTS is set to  -Djava.security.manager=allow
Buildfile: D:\Programs\Java\Projects\Swing Bank\run.xml

run:
     [java] Error: Unable to initialize main class swing.bank.SignUp
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser

BUILD FAILED
```

[GitHub Link to the project](https://github.com/warmachine028/Swing-Bank)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [help with ant file - classpath for Java task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988566/help-with-ant-file-classpath-for-java-task)

Comment: The solution is not working for me. I have tried as it was suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="Swing Bank" default="run" basedir="." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
    <description> ANT Run file for Running swing bank after compiling </description>
    <property name="dist.dir" value="dist"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="run" description="--> runs the project">
        <java classname="swing.bank.SignUp" classpathref="classpath" fork="true" failonerror="true" maxmemory="128m"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

The above is another way of doing it - specify the f.q. class name and classpath. N.B. I'm not 100% sure that is the main class as there are two with a `main` method

Comment: Actually this one is running the compiled files inside the build directory, but I want to run the jar file as I want to distribute it later on my GitHub.

Comment: Just make sure that the jar is *also* in the 'classpath' path and you'll be fine. You should only have jars in the fileset. Personally I like to use fat jars to obviate portability problems, but Ant doesn't have its own fat jar task (or at least didn't use to). I worked around that in the past by using `zipfileset` but that's a bit of a kludge and theoretically uncertain